# Combinatorics - divide objects into groups

Tags: combinatorics

How many different possibilities are there to divide $n$ different objects into 2 groups $A$ and $B$, if in group $A$ exactly $n_a$ objects in group $B$ exactly $n_b$ objects are to be assigned.

Since all n objects should be assigned to a group, $n_a + n_b = n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just $\binom n{n_a}$.

Choose the objects that go to $A$...the rest go to $B$ by default.